# Not-in-the-same-line radiobutton values

Tags: forms, radio-button, atk4

I'm building a "buffet menu list" form which has a lot of options for the "menu" radiobutton.
However I noted that all those values are "inline" just like in this example: http://demo.atk4.com/demo.html?t=14

I'd like to know in first instance how could I add a line break on every value, and then, how could I simulate groups by adding some sort of < p> < /p> between specific option values (logical grouping).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions I can think of.

Look at the examples here for some inspiration:

http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/grid/columns

### 1. Adding custom field to grid

First, create a form with no mark-up:

```
$form = $this->add('Form',null,null,array('form_empty'));
```

Next, add Grid into a form like this:

```
$grid = $form->add('Grid'); // or MVCGrid if you are using models
```

Add a column for selection:

```
$grid->addColumn('template','selection')
     ->setTemplate('<input type=radio name=selection value="<?$id?>"/>');
```

Finally - make sure the column 'selection' is first (or last)

```
$grid->addOrder()->move('selection','first')->now();
```

Finally you need to manually look into the POST data, because it's not a real form column.

```
if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $this->js()->univ()->successMessage('Selection is '+((int)$_POST['selection']))
          ->execute();
}
```

You must remember that accessing POST directly exposes you to injection attack and you must validate it properly. Grid also MUST be inside the form, however you can place submit button anywhere else on your page. You can also use "Form_Plain", see "http://agiletoolkit.org/whatsnew" for an example.

### 2. Using JavaScript and hidden field

In this example you can add a bunch of Radio button elements and tie them to a form. I've also using "Lister" here instead of "Grid", of course you can mix-and-match those approaches.

```
$form = $this->add('Form');
$selection = $form->addField('line','selection');
// can be placed anywhere.

$menu = $this->add('MVCLister',null,null,array('view/menu'));
$menu->setModel('MenuItems'); 

$menu->js(true)->find('input[type=radio]')->click(
    $selection->js()->_enclose()->val(
        $this->js()->_selectorThis()->val()
    );
);
// produces $('#menu_id').find('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
//    $('#selection_id').val( $(this).val() );
// }
```

Your view/menu.html template file could look like this:

```
<div class="menu-container">
<?rows?><?row?>
    <div><input type="radio" name="anything" value="<?$id?>"> <?$name?> </div>
<?/row?><?/rows?>
</div>
```

**EDIT: code which worked for Fernando**

```
$grid->addColumn('template','Menu')
    ->setTemplate('<input type=\'radio\' name=\'selection\' value="<?$value?>"/> <?$value?>');
if($form->isSubmitted()){
    $this->js()->univ()
         ->successMessage('Hoy: <b>'.$_POST['selection'].'</b>')->execute();
}
```

Comment: I opted for the solution #1, and it worked partially: While initially it worked and showed the menu ID in after posting, when I extended it to use the menu name itself as the key I started getting a zero value when posting. This is the code: 
`$grid->addColumn('template','Menu')->setTemplate('<input type=\'radio\' name=\'selection\' value="<?$name?>"/> <?$name?>');`

Comment: Ok, got it. The problem was concatenating with a PLUS sign while that's actually PHP code, so it needed a DOT.
This is working perfectly now:
`$grid->addColumn('template','Menu')->setTemplate('<input type=\'radio\' name=\'selection\' value="<?$value?>"/> <?$value?>');

if($form->isSubmitted()){
            $this->js()->univ()->successMessage('Hoy: <b>'.$_POST['selection'].'</b>')->execute();
        }`